# Getting user defined attribute values in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

Html

```
<input type="text" class="fulltextbox saving_field" dataid="1" dataname="temperature" dataunit="&deg; F" ng-model="addVt.Temp.value" />
```

js

```
    var tData = [];
angular.forEach(angSel('.saving_field'), function(v, k){
            console.log(v.dataname);
            tData.push({id: v.dataid, name: v.dataname, value: v.value, unit: v.dataunit});
    });
```

But I am getting `v.dataname` as undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the following attribute to access it:

```
v.dataset
```

Also, the data attributes should have a hyphen in them. Like `data-name` and not `dataname`.

So HTML would be:

```
<input type="text" class="fulltextbox saving_field" data-id="1" data-name="temperature" data-unit="&deg; F" ng-model="addVt.Temp.value" />
```

And in Javascript:

```
tData.push({id: v.dataset.id, name: v.dataset.name, value: v.value, unit: v.dataset.unit});
```

[See the documentation on how to properly use data attributes.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

Comment: and to get the value of its "class" attribute ? v.class gave undefined. v.dataset.class gave undefined.

Comment: You can generally use `getAttribute` http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/domattribute.shtml

Comment: or `className` for class specifically.

Comment: Thank you @nandeep mali for the answer and the link. It is very useful.